# inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

Not getting the the error

I am kinda new to c++ and c

anyone know a fix for this???

I have 0 idea whats going on for my thing

code:

```
#include "../sdk/includes.h"
#include "module/Module.h"
#include "module/ModuleManager.h"

namespace Link
{
    class c_link
    {
    private:
        JNIEnv* env;
        JavaVM* vm;

        jmethodID findclass;
        jobject cloassloader;

    public:
        bool attach();

        void hook();

        void run();
        
        void unload();

        const auto getEnv() { return env; }
        const auto getJavaVM() { return vm; }

        class std::unique_ptr<moduleManager, std::default_delete<moduleManager>> moduleMngr;
    };

    namespace hooks
    {
        using swapBuffersFunction = int(__stdcall*)(HDC);

        inline swapBuffersFunction oswapBuffers = nullptr;

        int __stdcall swapBuffersHook(HDC);

        
        inline WNDPROC originalWndproc = nullptr;

        long __stdcall wndproc(const HWND hwnd, unsigned int usermsg, uintptr_t wparam, long lparam);
    }

    extern std::unique_ptr<c_link> instance;
}
```

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? `inline specifier allowed on function declarations only` This: `inline swapBuffersFunction oswapBuffers = nullptr;` is not a function declaration, so `inline specifier` is NOT allowed here.

Comment: Why do you think the variables `originalWndProc` and `oswapBuffers` should be inline? I have trouble even conceptualizing what an inline instance variable even *means*.

Comment: *"anyone know a fix for this"* - uhhh remove the `inline` specifier.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious your name strangely fits this comment

Comment: You need to compile with C++17 or higher enabled for support of inline variables.

Comment: I will try that NathanOliver

Comment: NathanOliver Thank you for helping with the fix it worked :)